# Access route info in self hosted ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, self-hosting

I have a multi-tenant ASP.NET Web API that uses routes of the form

```
api/{tenant}/{controller}/{id}
```

Each tenant has a separate database and dependency injection (Ninject) is used to create a database connection (actually an NHibernate ISession) into my controllers for the request by parsing the route. I'm trying to write integration tests and the problem is that HttpContext.Current is null when the API is self-hosted, so I have no way to access route data and resolve the tenant for the request.

Is there a way to access the route info in a class in this scenario? If I were able to get the route data higher up in the pipeline, how could I push it to controllers in the current request context?

The only alternative I've come up with is to access the Request object in a controller but it's null in the constructor which is where I want to create the database connection.